# What does a wsgi server consist of?

Tags: python, server, uwsgi

I'm reading on the WSGI specification, and tried implementing a simple WSGI server from scratch, and tested it on a simple flask application. Currently it

- opens a socket listener
- passes each incoming connection to another thread to handle it
- the handler parses the request, creates the *environ*, passes it to the flask app object, and returns the response.

Overall, it seems to work. Conceptually, what more does a real server, eg. gunicorn do? I'm asking in terms of the basic functionality, not in terms of supporting more features (eg. different protocols). What makes a server better, eg. why is *gunicorn* suitable for production, but *wsgiref* is not?

Comment: I believe one potential reason wsgiref is potentially less suitable for production is a lack of support for concurrency. ref: https://github.com/Lawouach/WebSocket-for-Python/issues/143

Answer (score 1):

my 2c, is that getting *something* working is pretty easy, it's just that HTTP is such an old/complex standard it takes a lot of work to get all the edge cases working nicely

- how well does it tolerate errors in the WSGI client code
- HTTP 0.9, 1.0, 1.1 or 2/SPDY?
- how do you handle malicious clients that send a byte every 10 seconds
- the various Keep-Alive and Tranfer-Encoding variants seems to end up consuming a lot of code
- does it do Content-Encoding as well